# KDE 5.8.9 odd copy/paste behaviour

Tags: linux-mint, kde, clipboard

I am using Linux Mint 18.3 KDE Edition with KDE Plasma 5.8.9. As a file manager, I use the default "File" application but the issue I have may also be found with Thunar or Dolphin.

If I use the copy shortcut **Ctrl+C** for a file on the desktop (folder mode), then I realized I cannot copy it in a folder of the file manager. Both "**Ctrl+V**" and **right-click/paste** do not work.

However, if I copy the file using the shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+C** then I can paste it both ways.

I am puzzled with this behaviour as I cannot find any definition of the **Ctrl+Shift+C** shortcut in KDE... I know this is the default **copy** shortcut for konsole (which I installed) but I do not understand the link here...

Comment: dolphin here, none of ctrl+c neither ctrl+shift+c will work here, as I check with parcellite or any other application that should share the clipboard completely ignored by dolphin apparently :(. From this tip I can drag/drop it into yakuake, the file location at least, helps a little bit at least :/ https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=6997.0